# webapp2 application not running locally

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I am starting with [webapp2](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/quickstart.html). I have created an application at following directory.

```
/home/github_projects/hellowebapp2
```

But when I try to fire up a server using:

```
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py github_projects/hellowebapp2
```

I get following error:

```
This action requires the installation of components:  [app-engine-python]
You cannot perform this action because this Cloud SDK installation is 
managed by an external package manager.  If you would like to get the 
latest version, please see our main download page at:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 22, in main
    command=__file__)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 189, in EnsureInstalledAndRestart
    return manager._EnsureInstalledAndRestart(components, msg, command)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 1139, in _EnsureInstalledAndRestart
    restart_args=restart_args):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 660, in Install
    restart_args=restart_args)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 690, in Update
    self._EnsureNotDisabled()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 357, in _EnsureNotDisabled
    'The component manager is disabled for this installation')
googlecloudsdk.core.updater.update_manager.UpdaterDisableError: The component manager is disabled for this installation
```

P.S I have already installed sdk from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved this by installing specific python package from :

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#apt-get

> sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python